# Laravel: How to Populate Form with Values from Session

Tags: php, forms, session, laravel

I got this form which stores values into the Session, because it is a part of a multistep process. When you click next, the values are stored in the session and you are redirect to step 2.

Yet in Step 2 you have the option to get back to Step 1 for corrections. Now I want to populate the form of Step 1 with the values, that are already stored in the session, so that the user doesn't have to rewrite everything.

Here is the form of step 1:

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'orders.store', 'data-toggle' => 'validator', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('household_count', 'What is the householdCount?', ['class' => 'col-sm-2']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <label class="radio-inline">
                {!! Form::radio('householdCount', '1', false, ['required' => 'required']) !!} 1
                </label>

                <label class="radio-inline">
                {!! Form::radio('householdCount', '2', false, ['required' => 'required']) !!} 2
                </label>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('city', 'Where do you live?', ['class' => 'col-sm-2']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'e.g. Berlin', 'required']) !!}
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                {!! Form::submit('Next', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-next']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And here is the method that creates the the form.

```
public function step1() {
    return view('step1.create');
}
```

I already found this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/html#form-model-binding

But whenever I just replace the
     Form::open() 
with
     Form::model()

My Form just breaks and the form is not populated either.

Here is what is stored in my session:

```
{"_token":"iThJYWxZj3APr7Unzrczd4WrGfs6dGsUtKINyTIC","_previous":{"url":"http:\/\/uploader.dev"},"flash":{"old":[],"new":[]},"householdCount":"2","city":"adklf","comment":"akldfjlakdjf","comments":"lkjaldfj"}
```

So, how do I populate my form with the values, that are stored in this session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve your session data and populate it into an associative array. Then, pass that array to a `Form::model()` tag.

```
// Populate your array in the controller.
$data = [
  'name' => 'Cryode',
  'age'  => 29,
];

return View::make('myForm', ['modelData' => $data]);

// Use Form::model() in your view.
{{ Form::model($modelData, [ ... ]) }}
```

`Form::model()` does not require an Eloquent model. It can use a standard object or associative array as well.